# How does one iterate over an Array of Ranges?

Tags: swift

Swift 3's compiler will not let me compile the following:

```
let a = 0
let b = 10
var arr = [ClosedRange<Int>]()
let myRange: ClosedRange = a...b
arr.append(myRange)

for each in arr {
    for every in each {
        print(every)
    }
}
```

...due to `ClosedRange<Int>` not conforming to the `Sequence` protocol. In the past, a simple extension to the class like so would have been enough:

```
extension ClosedRange<Int>: Sequence {}
```

...but now the compiler asks that the extension be declared with a `where` clause, which makes me think that I'm going about this all wrong. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not that you have an array of ranges, but that 
[`ClosedRange`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/closedrange) in Swift 3 represents

> An interval over a comparable type, from a lower bound up to, and including, an upper bound.

For example, a closed range can be used with `Double`

```
let r: ClosedRange<Double> = 1.1...2.2
```

where enumerating all possible values does not make much sense.

What you need is [`CountableClosedRange`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/countableclosedrange) which is

> A closed range that forms a collection of consecutive values.

and in particular is a collection and can be iterated over:

```
let a = 0
let b = 10
var arr = [CountableClosedRange<Int>]()
let myRange: CountableClosedRange = a...b
arr.append(myRange)

for each in arr {
    for every in each {
        print(every)
    }
}
```

You can just write

```
let myRange = a...b
```

since by default, the `...` operator produces a `CountableClosedRange`
if its operands are `Strideable`.

Similarly there is `Range` and `CountableRange` for half-open ranges.
For more information, see [Range Types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0065-collections-move-indices.md#range-types) in [SE-0065 A New Model for Collections and Indices](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0065-collections-move-indices.md).

Comment: Aha! I had the wrong datatype. I'll get the hang of this one day. Thanks, @MartinR!

Answer (score 1):

```
    let a = 0
    let b = 10
    var arr = [ClosedRange<Int>]()
    let myRange: ClosedRange = a...b
    arr.append(myRange)

    for each in arr {
        for every in [Int](each.lowerBound..<each.upperBound) {
            print(every)
        }
    }
```

and remove that extention.

Comment: That is possible as well. Just note that it creates a *temporary array* of all integer values in the range.